# Optimize object initialization

Tags: c#, binary-tree

I have some class.

```
class TreeNode
{
    public TreeNode Left;
    public TreeNode Right;
    public int Value;

    public TreeNode(int i)
    {
        Value = i;
    }

    public TreeNode AddLeft(int value)
    {
        Left = new TreeNode(value); ;
        return Left;
    }
    public TreeNode AddRight(int value)
    {
        Right = new TreeNode(value);
        return Right;
    }
    public static int GetSum(TreeNode root)
    {
        if(root.Left == null || root.Right == null) return root.Value;
        return root.Value + GetSum(root.Left) + GetSum(root.Right);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var root = new TreeNode(10);
        var left = root.AddLeft(1);
        left.AddLeft(1);
        left.AddRight(1);
        var right = root.AddRight(1);
        right.AddLeft(1);
        right.AddRight(1);

        int Sum = TreeNode.GetSum(root);
        Console.WriteLine("Sum is :{0}", Sum);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

How to simplify the tree initialization because it is easy to get confused if the tree is big?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

something like this:

```
var root = new TreeNode(10,
    new TreeNode(1,
        new TreeNode(1),
        new TreeNode(1)),
    new TreeNode(1,
        new TreeNode(1),
        new TreeNode(1)));
```

looks cleaner, what do you think? All you need to do is add a new constructor:

```
public TreeNode(int value, TreeNode left, TreeNode right)
{
    Value = value;
    Left = left;
    Right = right;
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it by a nail :)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [Daren Thomas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9726612/4685) if you want the initialization to be a bit more readable, you can use the [named parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) feature of C# 4.0

```
var root = new TreeNode(10,
left: new TreeNode(1,
      left: new TreeNode(1),
      right: new TreeNode(1)),
right: new TreeNode(1,
      left: new TreeNode(1),
      right: new TreeNode(1)));
```

Comment: +1, i like this! sadly, due to programming to a hosted API that currently only supports .NET 3.5, i'm not used to the 4.0 features yet...

Answer (score 1):

Create an XML representation or JSON representation for your tree, that you can load or save too.

Answer (score 1):

C# object initializers could provide a more terse code, plus why need an extra constructor  for something that's supported by the language.

```
    public class TreeNode
    {
        public TreeNode Left { get; set; }
        public TreeNode Right { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var root = new TreeNode { Left = new TreeNode {Left = new TreeNode() }, 
                                  Right = new TreeNode() };

    }
```